# Heegner points on elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

I want to know about Heegner point computations for a CM elliptic curve. What is the best reference book/paper for reading?

Comment: I might be wrong, but my guess is that we do not expect anything particular to happen when the elliptic curve you map the Heegner points to has complex multiplication.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Sure we do: we get the so-called Rubin's formula. See Rubin's Inventiones 107 paper.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are interested in the practical aspects of Heegner point computation, check out Elkies' paper "Heegner point computations" (Lec notes in computer science 877, 1994) where he describes a practical algorithm for computing Heegner points on GENERAL (i.e. not necessarily CM) curves.

On a related note:  In "Computing rational points on rank 1 elliptic curves via L-series and canonical heights" (Math of Computation v.68, 1999), Silverman compares various known methods, including Rubin's paper, and there are several good numerical examples.